# c++ standard_layout for ref types

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to understand why `standard_layout` does not apply to ref types?

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

struct X {
    int y;
};

static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<X>);
static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<X&>); // does not compile
```

Comment: Why would it apply to a reference type?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994042/c-standard-layout-and-references

Comment: Why is this tagged c++11? `is_standard_layout_v` [was introduced in C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've found, `is_standard_layout` only works with an object type, not a reference.

As such, if you want either a type or a reference to a type, you could use:

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<std::remove_reference_t<X>>);
```

`remove_reference_t` will yield the referred-to type for a reference, or the type itself if what you pass isn't a reference (note: for older compilers, you can use `std::remove_reference<T>::type`).

Comment: @user17732522; Fair enough; edited, with my thanks.

Comment: any reason not to prefer `remove_reference_t` now?

Comment: @RyanHaining: No, not really. Obviously it's compatible with older compilers, but given that he's already using `is_standard_layout_v`, that doesn't gain anything in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Because a standard layout type is defined by [the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) in from [basic.types]:

> - Scalar types
> - standard-layout class types
> - arrays of such types and
> - cv-qualified versions of these types
>
> are collectively called standard-layout types.

The list of things that constitute a standard-layout class type is rather long (cf. [class]) but a reference is obviously not a class.

In particular that list says nothing about references, so a reference to even a standard-layout type (like `int` or `float const[16]`) is not standard-layout itself.